# How to get an array of all pending remote notification?

Tags: ios, iphone

Scenario:

1. My application is closed  (not in background).
2. I received more than 1 remote notification.
3. I click on app icon (not on remote notifications).

How can I get array of `JSON` payload for received remote notification (more than 1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately this is not possible.**

You will **only** receive information about the notification that was used to open your app. If a user opens your app, and you have more than one notification, you will not be able to retrieve all of them from in the app.

Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded.

[Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: it 'sucks' but thats how it is :(

Comment: You can use  "UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications" method to get all notifications of an app delivered to your iPhone

Answer (score 3):

**APNs**

> **Quality of Service**
>
> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that were being stored for it are discarded.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

**iOS**

You can get a hold on **only the last remote notification**.

Answer (score 3):

As iOS 10 it is possible

```
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {
    NSLog(@"msg getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler count %lu", [notifications count]);
       }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
func getAllDeleveredPendingNotifications() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
            print("pending notifications \(notifications)")
            for info in notifications {
                let userInfo = info.request.content.userInfo
                print("UserInfo is  \(userInfo)")
            }
            self.removeAllPendingNotification()
        }
    }
```